# Python: And or condition doesn't work properly like if else

Tags: python, syntax, conditional-statements

I'm working with python and i realize that itsn't reliable while sometimes and or statement doesn't work properly without reason

```
column_exclude_list = []}
column_exclude_edit = ['id']
def get_columns(type='list'):
    # exclude_list = column_exclude_list if type=='list' else column_exclude_edit
    exclude_list = type=='list' and column_exclude_list or column_exclude_edit

    print(type)
    print(column_exclude_list)
    print(column_exclude_edit)
    print(exclude_list)
```

I tested with this function and it prints:

```
list
[]
['id']
['id']
```

After changing to `exclude_list = column_exclude_list if type=='list' else column_exclude_edit`, it works.

```
list
[]
['id']
[]
```

What's wrong between these two short-hand conditions?

Comment: You should really be using a *conditional expression*.

Comment: Assuming Python, one of the most used language isn't reliable and that 'and' is broken is a little far fetched.

Comment: "and i realize that itsn't reliable while sometimes and or statement doesn't work properly without reason". Why do you think there is no reason?

Comment: What happens is if `column_exclude_list` is empty, it **doesn't matter what `type` is set to**.

Comment: @MartijnPieters of course. good point.

Comment: `or` has a lower [precendence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) than `and`. So this comes down to assuming `2 + 3 *  4 = 20` and suggesting `+` is broken if Python says something else. (The same solution to get `20` would also work for your `and/or`.)

Comment: @usr2564301: not sure this is a confusion about precedence. The OP just didn't think through what `True and False or 'something else'` would produce. Not realising that the second expression in the equation (the result to be returned if the first is 'truthy') is *still used to determine the outcome of the second test* is a classic error when using boolean operators to emulate a conditional expression.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: the parenthesized part hinted at a possible solution. Would that not work, then?

Comment: @usr2564301: it would not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't accounted for the case where `column_exclude_list` is **empty**. An empty list is a false-y value:

```
>>> type_ = 'list'
>>> column_exclude_list = []
>>> column_exclude_edit = 'column_exclude_edit'  # for demo purposes
>>> type_ == 'list' and column_exclude_list or column_exclude_edit
'column_exclude_edit'
```

Because `column_exclude_list` is a false value, the `and` operator produces an empty list and the `or` operator produces the other operand.

This doesn't mean that `and` and `or` are broken or work differently in Python than they do in other languages. You just haven't considered that in a `<test> and <true expression> or <false expression>` construct, that the `<true expression>` is *still used to determine the outcome of the whole*. This applies to all boolean logic, not just Python.

Don't use `and` and `or` for a conditional expression. Use an actual [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions), so `<true expression> if <test> else <false expression>`:

```
column_exclude_list if type_ == 'list' else column_exclude_edit
```

Like `and` and `or`, this lazily evaluates either one of the two operand expressions based on the outcome of the `if` test. If `column_exclude_list` is empty, it'll still be returned, because it's value is not used to determine the outcome of further boolean testing.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out, i thought `and or` condition simply works like `? :` in other language, but it doesn't.

Comment: @TomSawyer: no, `? :` is a conditional expression. Python's syntax for the same construct is the one I show here. `and` and `or` work the same in many other programming languages as they do in Python, and should not be used for conditional expressions either.

Comment: @TomSawyer: put differently, what would you expect `True and False or 'other option'` to produce in other languages?